# Azure Backup Failed "VM agent is unable to communicate with the Azure Backup Service"

Tags: backup, windows-server-2008, azure-virtual-machine

I am receiving a backup failed error since 6/20/2020 within my Azure backup policy.

I also noticed within the Properties section under Settings of the Virtual Machine instance the "Agent status" is in a "Not Ready" state.

When I click the Backup section under Operations the Backup Status shows 2 entries.

Backup Pre-Check Warning

Last backup status Failed

I can click the Warning option and the link takes me to a page that reads:

Issue Description

VM agent is unable to communicate with the Azure Backup Service.

Suggested Action(s)

Ensure that VM agent is latest and running. Allow access to IP 168.63.129.16
Per the Suggested Actions, I created the Outbound Rule to the IP Address 168.63.129.16 within the network interface of the Virtual Machine instance that is having the backup failed issue.

That did not solve the problem. I also performed the below troubleshooting steps as well with no solution:

I also Verified the Windows Azure Guest Agent service is running within services on the affected VM OS (ACMVI002).

Stopped the VM instance from the Azure Portal. I then turned the VM instance back on. Issue persisted.

Does anyone have a solution to this Backup Failed issue?

Comment: This is badly formatted. Please accept the edit as edit queue is full.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to re-install the Backup extension. Take a backup of whole registry then use following steps:

1. Login to the affected machine.
2. Open Registry Editor.
3. Remove VMSnapshot registry keys at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Azure\HandlerState`
4. Remove or rename VMSnapshot Plugin Folders at `C:\Packages\Plugins`.
5. Now, open command prompt as admin and run below commands to force the extension installation:

   - `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BcdrAgent" /v IsProviderInstalled /t REG_SZ /d False /f`
   - `REG ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\BcdrAgentPersistentKeys" /v IsCommonProviderInstalled /t REG_SZ /d False /f`
6. Restart the Service "WindowsAzureGuestAgent".
7. Trigger a manual backup. As a part of backup, extension will be re-installed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You probably still don't have access to 168.63.129.16 or your agent is too old, this is a global Microsoft IP used to facilitate a communication channel to Azure platform resources, more details you can read this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/what-is-ip-address-168-63-129-16).

Azure Backup needs Azure Agent up to date, you can have an old Agent, but depends on how old it is, you can have issue, please refer to this page for [more details](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4049215/extensions-and-virtual-machine-agent-minimum-version-support).

You can try to update your Azure Agent manually, [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/agent-windows) it is information about it.

- From C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\WaAppAgent.txt you see some options to try to identify your issue, version of your Agent appears.

```
[00000006] [06/25/2020 20:31:00.34] [INFO]  WindowsAzureGuestAgent starting. Version 2.7.41491.971
```

- From C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\WaSecAgent-startPoll.txt you see logs from your VM to 168.63.129.16

```
[2020/06/25 20:31:02:176] Info:WaSecWireServerProxy:: Will start polling for Uri 168.63.129.16 , poll time 900000 ms, running time 21600000 ms
[2020/06/25 20:31:02:176] Verbose:WaSecWireServerProxy:: - WireServerProxy::StartCACertsUpdater
[2020/06/25 20:31:02:176] Info:WaSecWireServerProxy:: Current process is the primary process for polling
[2020/06/25 20:31:02:176] Info:WaSecWireServerProxy:: CA certs polling called for 168.63.129.16, poll interval 900000
[2020/06/25 20:31:02:176] Verbose:WaSecWireServerProxy:: - WireServerProxy::StartCACertsUpdater0x0
[2020/06/25 20:31:02:176] Info:WaSecWireServerProxy:: Starting CA Cert Polling Thread
```

- From the same file C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\WaAppAgent.txt you see logs about RecoveryServices

```
[00000010] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.54] [INFO]  Initialize ExtensionWorkflow for 'FastTrack GS: SeqNo=3'.
[00000009] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.57] [INFO]  Plugin Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot 1.0.65.0 not found in cache.
[00000010] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.57] [INFO]  Plug-in Microsoft.EnterpriseCloud.Monitoring.MicrosoftMonitoringAgent 1.0.18038.1 found in cache.
[00000009] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.59] [INFO]  Starting download of plugin version manifest Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot from location: https://zrdfepirv2bl4prdstr03.blob.core.windows.net/80afa74b14194a679c6347109557b7ee/Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices_VMSnapshot_useast_manifest.xml
[00000009] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.59] [WARN]  Downloading version manifest via HostGAPlugin for plugin Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot from https://zrdfepirv2bl4prdstr03.blob.core.windows.net/80afa74b14194a679c6347109557b7ee/Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices_VMSnapshot_useast_manifest.xml.
[00000010] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.59] [INFO]  Test extract the plugin zip file to the temp folder C:\windows\TEMP\b4162b75-fe14-4669-8ed5-e283671cb293
[00000009] [06/25/2020 20:58:15.62] [INFO]  Download finished for plugin version manifest Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot.
```

- Some logs here too

```
C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.RecoveryServices.VMSnapshot\1.0.65.0
```

In case anything helped, consider open up a ticket to Microsoft, it could be a issue on Microsoft side that we don't have access to investigate it further.